# How can I implement a "horizontal desynced colors" effect in LWJGL?

Tags: lwjgl, effect

My plan is to achieve analog video effects like RGB channel desynchronisation.

I'd like to have something like this (I hope you get the idea):
[image: My effect - This one i manually made with gimp]
Left: White dot; Right: The same dot, but mind the channel offsets (the center should be brighter and white).

Comment: So your actual goal is to implement the effect shown?

Comment: @JoshPetrie exctly. and some other like RGB noise, bad VSync, i hae some ideas for code, and i think i could achievethem if i could get to the display data like one could do in a fashion of poking values into mem adresses bound to video on devices like C64 etc.

Comment: Well, you can't get the display data directly on modern hardware, and LWJGL is just an OpenGL wrapper. You can get a copy of the GL backbuffer's pixel data, but updating and copying it back is slow. Better to do this in a shader instead.

Comment: This type of effect is commonly known as "chromatic aberration" - you should be able to find shader examples by searching on that name.